# SSH multiple terminal MAC

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, remote-access

I have to log in remotely to do my work. Is there any way I can log into the same machine and have more than one terminal in my laptop? I can SSH multiple time but it's not efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not efficient"? Also, out of the 16 questions you asked, are you sure that *none* of them have been answered?

Comment: I'll happily migrate this over to SuperUser if you can explain *"I can SSH multiple time but it's not efficient."*.

Answer (score 4):

use `screen`. it is a program allowing you to have multiple shells on the same tty and switch between them.

[man screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

[screen command examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/)

Comment: screen is awesome. That is a life changing program once you get the key combos down.

Comment: ...or change them to your liking: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Key-Binding :D

Comment: That's interesting. Prob. better just to learn the defaults though in case you find yourself out of your own environment.

Comment: yeah.. probably mostly useful if your terminal/Xserver/mental constitution or similar conflict with the defaults

Comment: Don't forget to accept Gung Foo's answer :) He deserves them points.

Answer (score 4):

As Gung Foo said, **screen** is the way to go. Also check out Total Terminal a hot-key toggled dropdown terminal for mac, with tabs.

http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/